# Disabling antialiasing for all letters including Greek

Tags: fonts

(On Arch Linux) run `emacs -q` and evaluate `(set-face-font 'default ":antialias=false")`.
Your font should now not be smooth any more.  But type something with Greek
letters (οἷον ταῦτα): they will still be smooth.  Why?  And how can one turn off
antialiasing for all letters including Greek?

From `describe-char` on normal and Greek symbol respectively:

```
             position: 17192 of 43717 (39%), column: 0
            character: 1 (displayed as 1) (codepoint 49, #o61, #x31)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x31
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 31" or "C-x 8 RET DIGIT ONE"
          buffer code: #x31
            file code: #x31 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x14)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: DIGIT ONE
  general-category: Nd (Number, Decimal Digit)
  decomposition: (49) ('1')

There are text properties here:
  org-category         "met"

[back]


             position: 17202 of 43717 (39%), column: 10
            character: λ (displayed as λ) (codepoint 955, #o1673, #x3bb)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x03BB
               script: greek
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, G:2-byte Greek, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, g:Greek, h:Korean, j:Japanese
             to input: type "l" with greek-daedalus input method
          buffer code: #xCE #xBB
            file code: #xCE #xBB (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x309)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMDA
  old-name: GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (955) ('λ')

There are text properties here:
  org-category         "met"

[back]
```

Comment: What platform are you on? Does turning off antialiasing seem to make a difference for you outside of Emacs? Does the question really have to do with Greek, or do you see the same thing in general?

Comment: @Drew, Arch Linux.  I can turn it off in the terminal by inserting `:antialias=false` after the font specification in `.Xresources`.  There Greek is affected too.  In Emacs, antialiasing can be turned off, only the Greek glyphs are still antialiased.

Comment: Please add such info to your question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: Try posting info from `C-u C-x =` when point is on a Greek letter, and when on a non-Greek letter. Perhaps it will have some useful hints about the fonts in use.

Comment: @npostavs, added.